# Repo disappearing from local when changing branches on VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, branch, local

When changing branches on the current repo I'm working on, some branches will allow me to view the repo in browser whereas selecting other branches will cause that same repo to disappear from the list of repos upon page refresh.

Win10, VS Code, Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had branched off an old branch whose .htaccess file was configured for Apache 2.2 as opposed to 2.4 which I'm currently using.

The 2.2 had version had Order which was changed to Require for 2.4.

In this example, there is no authentication and all requests are denied.

2.2 configuration:
Order deny,allow

Deny from all

2.4 configuration:
Require all denied

[Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)